# Error calling method from one script to another in Unity

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, methods, scripting

1st script:

```
public class VRTK_VRInputModule : PointerInputModule
```

Method in in:

```
public virtual void Click(VRTK_UIPointer pointer, List<RaycastResult> results)
```

2nd script:

```
public class ARHeadWebCamTextureExample : MonoBehaviour
```

Im trying to call Click from the 1st script by using:

```
public VRTK_VRInputModule vrtk;

vrtk = new VRTK_VRInputModule();
            vrtk.Click();
```

Im getting an error: The type or namespace name `VRTK_VRInputModule' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

What am I doing wrong??

EDIT:

I created a "using VRTK" but got another error:

```
using OpenCVForUnity;
using DlibFaceLandmarkDetector;
using VRTK;
namespace DlibFaceLandmarkDetectorExample {

public class ARHeadWebCamTextureExample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public VRTK_VRInputModule vrtk;

        public void NeededFunction()
        {            
          vrtk = new VRTK_VRInputModule();
          vrtk.Click();
        }
    } 
}
```

When hoovering over Click I get the following error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33DI7.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `VRTK_VRInputModule` is in a different namespace. You are missing `using`. How come there is no duplicate for such a frequent question?

Comment: Could you please check the lines just before the class declarations? If you see any 'namespace' construct, you should use this namespace on the other class so you can access it's content

Comment: @rob EDIT posted. Any help would be appreciated!!!